# How to get clarification on old answers from inactive users?

Tags: discussion

I thought I had seen this question asked before on Meta but now I can't find it.

I had a question recently about "how to convert a large particle system to an object efficiently?"  I found the question on BSE and it has an accepted, well-received answer.  However, to me the answer's unclear as it seems to assume a certain level of understanding that I apparently don't possess.  Both the inquirer and responder are now inactive.

So the generalized question is: ***How can I get more clarification on an answer without asking a duplicate question?***

Comment: Without asking new question? Well, probably impossible if meaning using only the site tools. You could ask that in chat maybe and probably answer which is unclear for you will be edited (or maybe you will end asking that question and receiving an answer, or you will search fori info elsewhere and edit the answer yourself). I don't think you can generally avoid asking new question, and maybe you shouldn't

Comment: link to this answer please.

Comment: @David - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1389/convert-large-particle-systems-to-one-object-efficiently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just ask a new question, making a reference (and including the link) to the other question as part of the text, and explain what part of the process you are stuck with. when it comes to old questions, it is also possible that new tools are available and couldn't have been part of the original answer.